# Getting "peer not authenticated" exception on Amazon SQS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

When running the following code from a JAR locally:

```
public static List<Message> getMessages(AmazonSQS sqs, String queueUrl) throws IOException {
    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl).withWaitTimeSeconds(5);
    List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
    return messages;
}
```

It works just fine. But when trying to run it remotely on an EC2 instance, I get the following exception:

> Apr 15, 2014 8:30:48 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient
>   executeHelper INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not
>   authenticated javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not
>   authenticated
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:371)
>           at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:126)
>           at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:1
>   80)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
>           at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:384)
>           at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
>           at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2170)
>           at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:942)
>           at Utils.getMessages(Utils.java:80)
>           at Manager.run(Manager.java:51)
>           at Main.main(Main.java:10)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)

Searching for these exceptions only brought up questions by people who use the HttpClient explicitly, along with solutions which seem very irrelevant for my usage.

Comment: Using the same permissions in both cases?

Comment: Yes. is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was I used the wrong AMI, with incompatible JRE.