# Mule SQS Connector throwing javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, ssl, mule, mule-studio

I have a problem sending and receiving messages using Mule SQS Connector. Mule starts ok but throws javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated exception when i try to send or receive  messages.
I am using keystores for other https outbounds.
Here is my flow

```
<sqs:config name="Amazon_SQS" accessKey="${AMAZON.ACCESS.KEY}"
    secretKey="${AMAZON.SECRET.KEY}" queueName="${AMAZON.QUEUE.NAME}"
     doc:name="Amazon SQS">
</sqs:config>

<flow name="TestFlow" doc:name="TestFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8081" path="post" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <set-payload
        value="#['hello']"
        doc:name="Set Payload" />
    <json:object-to-json-transformer
        doc:name="Object to JSON" />
    <sqs:send-message config-ref="Amazon_SQS" doc:name="Amazon SQS"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this question [Getting "peer not authenticated" exception on Amazon SQS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094316/getting-peer-not-authenticated-exception-on-amazon-sqs) I'm wondering what JRE are you using? Do you have a recent Oracle JRE?

Per this blog post http://myjavacodeworld.blogspot.ca/2012/12/javaxnetsslsslpeerunverifiedexception.html, it seems you could use `-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking=true` to bypass the issue.

Comment: Thanks David.I am using jdk7. Also where should I put the check to bypass the issue. In mule properties?

Comment: Ok got it working. Ive removed all the keystores in the app and added the certificates in cacerts. All working good now.